# Every group is solvable, fake proof.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, fake-proofs

We use induction on $n$, the number of distinct prime factors of the order of $G$.

If $n=1$ then $G$ is a $p$-group which is solvable

Now assume this for some $k$. Let $G$ be a group of order with $k+1$ distinct prime factors. Then $G$ has a sylow p-subgroup, $H$. Then $\dfrac{G}{H}$ has order with $k$ distinct prime factors, so its solvable by our assumption. But $H$ is also solvable hence $G$ is solvable wich completes the induction step.

Thus every group is solvable. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Pffft, fake news!

Comment: The most serious mistake is that you appear to be assuming that all groups are finite which, for some reason that I do not understand, seems to be surprisingly common in this forum.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I suppose that nowadays a "tag" of (finite-groups) is regarded as taking the place of a hypothesis :-/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Sylow subgroup of a group is normal if and only if it’s the only one of its kind.

Comment: Because all sylow subgroups are conjugate, I remember now :(